# How do prevent a field with a conditional statement from disappearing while a user is editing it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a bootstrap datepicker field. It has a prefilled date that is sent from a database, but sometimes there is no prefilled date. In that case I want the field to be invisible.
The problem is that IF there is a prefilled date AND the user deletes the date to enter a new one, the field will disappear because the condition says that there needs to be data inside the field for it to be visible.

```
    <b-form-row>
      <b-col lg="6">
        <b-form-group v-if="preEnteredDate">
          <b-date-picker
            v-model="preEnteredDate"
          />
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
    </b-form-row>
```

So my question is, how do I prevent the v-if from triggering when the user empties the field? I still want it to be hidden if no prefilled date is present, but IF there is a prefilled date present AND the user wants to change this, I want the field to remain visible if the user empties it before entering a new date.

Comment: If preEnteredDate is in another data than you're v-model the field shouldn't disapear when is cleared. Can you show us you're script ?

Comment: My apologies. The v-model is the same as the variable in the v-if. I have just edited my code example.

Comment: So I think you should use another data for you're v-if, and after you're api call you do a verification like : 
if (this.preEnteredDate) {
  this.showInput = true;
} else {
  this.showInput = false;
}